# Could not serve pdf file from Lambda function on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, aws-lambda, cloud

I am trying to serve a pdf file that is in my zip folder (on the root directory as index.js file) which i have uploaded onto the Lambda web console.

```
const express = require("express");
const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.all("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./document.pdf"));
});



module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

Then I configure HTTP API endpoint for the lambda function it provides me a URL which after going to gives me a "404" message all description of the API is on the below image

[API configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4xJS.png)

[File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdXRf.png)

What am I doing Wrong?

Tried changing many configuration didn't work

Comment: Where is the document.pdf file located? Is your `/` route handler being called (add logging to the code and check for logs in CloudWatch Logs)?

Comment: file is located on the root folder. I have uploaded the file structure also.

Comment: It doesn't appear in the file listing you included, unless document.pdf is a placeholder for the hidden name. Anyhow, add some logging to your code. Use the os module to list the files available in the relevant directory, for example. Is the PDF present under `__dirname__`? And what is the value of `__dirname__`?

Comment: `__dirname` is a keyword provided by the path module. It gives the path of the root folder. [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-__dirname-variable/)

Comment: Right, but what files are in the `__dirname` folder? Is the requested PDF actually present there?

Comment: yes, whose name I scraped on the image is the pdf i am serving. the document name on code is mere placeholder I was running the right code with right name during testing.

Comment: also checked cloudwatch logs it was a "-" at the position of the error.